# Blender slaves timeout after rendring few or part of frame

Tags: rendering, network

I have a setup of 4 slaves and the master for the netrender. I also have slave on the master itself. After sending the job, through client, frames are properly dispatched and we could see the blender render process on each machine. After some time, all slaves start throwing timeout errors except for the slave on the master. Eventually the only slave working remains the slave on the master machine. I guess it is something related to http timeout. I couldn't figure out why this is happening. any help is appreciated. I could also edit master.py or any other script as a workaround. System Ubuntu, blender 2.7 on all machines.

Comment: What OS are you using on slaves